# Getting Lookup Column Data from SharePoint list to another SharePoint list

Tags: list, microsoft-lists

I want Sharepoint List A columns (A,B,C) to look up to Sharepoint lists (1,2,3). The columns from List A should pull the data from Sharepoint lists 1,2,3. Rather than manually adding each lookup column row by row. How can I get the columns to pre fill with the data being retrieved from lists 1,2,3.